# How to prove convergence of sequence $a_n$ if convergence is given for a 2nd series built from $a_n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Prove or disprove, if $a_n$ is a sequence so that
$$\lim\limits_{n \to ∞} \frac{5a_n+3}{12-2a_n} = 3$$
Then $a_n$ is convergent.

I believe it is provable, and I tried to prove via the definition of limit of a sequence:
$\lim\limits_{n \to ∞}b_n$=$\lim\limits_{n \to ∞} |\frac{5a_n+3}{12-2a_n}-3|<ε$, and then again for $a_n$, but I really don't know how to continue from here and which theorems that are applicable to a sequence that is defined with an n index are applicable to a sequence defined with $a_n$.

Please excuse any misused terms as I am learning calculus in a different language, and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let $b_n:=\frac{5a_n+3}{12-2a_n}.$

Now show that

$$a_n=\frac{12b_n-3}{2b_n+5}.$$

Since $b_n \to 3$, we get $a_n \to \frac{36-3}{6+5}=3.$

Comment: Thank you! This is a lot more simple than I thought

Answer (score 0):

Suppose instead you had the equation
$$\frac{5a_n+3}{12-2a_n}=3.$$
What would this imply about $a_n$? How would the answer change if you changed "$3$" by a small amount?